# File upload nodejs to server

Tags: node.js, forms, module

I want to upload files of my form to my server.

I have already test [this](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) but i haven't a success.

What is the best npm module for that ?
Can i test it in localhost ?

Thanks

Comment: Please hive some more detail on what exactly is going wrong. Also, please give us as specific of a question as possible, including a code example if relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Express Use,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

For Hapi.js

https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/0c6bd5135d7edeba7b87

Hope This Helps!

Comment: I used multer. Perfect to my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Hapijs

I have done Image upload in one of my projects

I had Used Nginx to define my root location for this file upload.

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var path = require('path');
var mv = require('mv');
exports.imageUpload = function (req, reply) {

var payload = req.payload;
commonImageUpload(payload.uploadFile,urid,function(err,res){

});

}


var commonImageUpload = function (file, idUser, callback) {
if (null != file) {

    var extention = path.extname(file.filename);

    var extentionsList = [];
    extentionsList.push('.jpg');
    extentionsList.push('.png');
    extentionsList.push('.jpeg');
    extentionsList.push('.gif');

    var index = extentionsList.indexOf(extention.toLowerCase());
    if (index < 0) {
        callback(true,"Invalid Media Type");
    } else {
        var filepath;

         filepath = '../cdn/idcard/';

        var fname = filepath + idUser + extention;
        console.log(fname);
        mkdirp(filepath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(true,"Internal Server Error");
            }
            else {
                mv(file.path, fname, function (err) {

                });
            }
        });

    }

} else {
    callback(true);
}
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.